# Find the missing element in a given permutation

Tags: arrays, swift, compare, reduce

First, a bit of background:

I'm working on one of [the Codility lessons](https://codility.com/programmers/lessons/3-time_complexity/perm_missing_elem/), and, even though this is easy to solve, logistically, it is less than easy to solve, performance-wise.

I've been able to boil it down to just this:

```
public func solution(_ A : inout [Int]) -> Int {
    let B = A   // Assigning it to a local speeds it up.
    return Array<Int>(Set(B)).sorted(by: {$0<$1}).reduce(0) { ($1 == $0 + 1) ? $1 : $0 } + 1
}
```

However, this is just a *WEE* bit too slow. I guess that the main reason is that the reduce goes through ALL elements of an array, even though the answer may be early. I may not be able to speed it up.

But I'd like to try. The part that I'm looking at is this:

```
.reduce(0) { ($1 == $0 + 1) ? $1 : $0 }
```

I'm wondering if I can make that comparison more efficient.

I have to check if $1 is equal to $0 + 1. I can't avoid that comparison.

The ternary operator is not actually faster than an if clause, but it looks cooler ;).

Is there a higher-performance way to compare two positive integers for equivalence than the basic "==" operator?

BTW: This is not a "do my homework for me" question. It's pretty legit, and these Codility lessons don't give you credit or anything. They are just a fun exercise. I want to know how to do this, as I'm sure I'll need it in the future.

Comment: Maybe I misread the question but can't you just add up all the numbers in the array and then subtract it from the summation of 1 to n + 1 to get the missing number?

Comment: Hmm... I'll try that. One of the reasons that I like Codility is that they have some SERIOUSLY sneaky unit tests. It may break one of their weird corner cases.

Comment: Cant you use A.sorted(by..... - Codility says that you should assume the list is distinct. So there is no reason to first create a set.

Comment: @LittleGreenViper try that out and let me know if it fails a certain case, i'm geniuenly curious

Comment: The set is in response to one of those sneaky corner cases. It forces each element to be unique, and weeds out dupes. It is a real challenge, figuring out some of these unit tests, as they don't really tell you what they are, and you have to interpolate them.

Comment: @TNguyen: It sort of...works. It works on the examples they give, but borks on a couple of corner cases. This may be due to my knuckleheadedness. It looks like it could be a cool solution. I'll keep working on it.

Comment: The problem is not that the comparison is too slow, but that you are using the wrong algorithm, in particular sorting the numbers makes it slow. – This is a well-known programming task, just google for *"find the missing number"*, for example here: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-missing-number/.

Comment: @Martin R: Thanks so much! Yeah, my initial code training was about 30 years ago, and it's been production coding since, so I missed out on all the CS stuff that has coalesced since. Not an issue. That's why I'm doing this, and I appreciate your not laughing at me too hard.

Comment: Also, it turns out the sorting wasn't needed. I had re-used code from another solution that did need it (maybe -I'll revisit it). I appreciate the GeeksForGeeks link. One reason that I like Codility is that they implement Swift, and I'm trying to keep my focus on Swift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the solution suggested by @[TNguyen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5896260/tnguyen) in comments, below piece of code got 100% on both correctness and performance.

You just need to generate the correct Array, containing each Integer in the range `[1..(N + 1)]` by calling `Array(1...A.count+1)`. Then you sum its elements using `reduce(0,+)` and finally substract the sum of the elements of the input array `A`. The difference between the two sums gives the missing element.

```
public func solution(_ A : inout [Int]) -> Int {
    return Array(1...A.count+1).reduce(0,+)-A.reduce(0,+)
}
```

An even faster solution is to use the mathematical formula`1+2+...+n=n(n-1)/2` for the first sum.

```
public func solution(_ A : inout [Int]) -> Int {
    return (A.count+1)*(A.count+2)/2-A.reduce(0,+)
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect, you do not need to sum 1..n+1 like that. There is a formula! `1+ 2+ ... + n = n(n+1) / 2,`

Comment: @TNguyen this isn't incorrect. It might be suboptimal, but definitely not incorrect, since the result is the same as n*(n-1). However, updated my answer to reflect the faster solution.

Comment: given that he's trying to do it the most fastest way possible I would say this is incorrect. I reversed my downvote as well.

Comment: This borks on a couple of my unit tests. I'll have to review them, to see if I'm being fair... Thanks for the input. This is one of the reasons I like this site. It helps me to look at things from a different direction.

Comment: @LittleGreenViper this solution actually passes all tests, see my submitted solution with the results [here](https://codility.com/demo/results/trainingY6N59M-TG3/)

Comment: You BOTH de man! I confirm it works beautifully. @TNgyuyen: Post an answer, and I'll give you an upvote. David's was the full solution, but you started it.

Answer (score 1):

100% score in python using an other concept:

```
def solution(A):
 Index=0;
 while (Index<len(A)):
  while((A[Index]-1) != Index and A[Index]<=len(A)):
   Tmp=A[Index]; #Permut
   A[Index]=A[Tmp-1];
   A[Tmp-1]=Tmp;
  Index+=1;
 Index=0;
 while Index<len(A):
  if((A[Index]-1) != Index) :
   return Index+1;
  else:
   Index+=1;
 return len(A)+1;  
pass
```

The idea behind is that for a given permutation, each element A[Index]-1 should match to Index except for the missing element. Elements of the array are then permuted until the correspondence is achieved or not achieved when A[Index]>len(A).